When does $G^{\otimes n}$ vs $G^{\dagger \otimes n}$ implement $G$ transversally
Given an $[[n,1]]$ or $((n,2))$ code and a $2 \times 2$ matrix $G$ in its transversal group.
There are cases when $G^{\otimes n}$ acts on $|\bar 0 \rangle,|\bar 1\rangle$ the same way as $G$ on $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ but $G^{\dagger \otimes n}$ doesn't; and cases where things are reversed. I'd like know what property of $G$ distinguishes between the two. (Of course if $G^\dagger=G$ then there are no issues; so we can assume $G^\dagger \neq G$).
